How to merge Landsat data on different paths in R
I am trying to merge four landsat (derived product) images available at https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MEASURES/GFCC30TC.003/2000.01.01/. You will have to have a NASA Earthdata login username to access the data which you can easily sign up for here https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/users/new/.
The images are p172r061_TC_2000.tif, p172r062_TC_2000.tif, p173r061_TC_2000.tif, p173r062_TC_2000.tif, which should cover all of Rwanda.
One can read the data in with terra::rast()
p173r62 <- rast("p173r062_TC_2000.tif")
p173r61 <- rast("p173r061_TC_2000.tif")
p172r62 <- rast("p172r062_TC_2000.tif")
p172r61 <- rast("p172r061_TC_2000.tif")

Images on path 172 have the same CRS. But images on different paths (172 vs 173) have different CRSs. terra::crs(p172r62) produces:
"PROJCRS[\"WGS 84 / UTM zone 36N\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n        DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4326]],\n    CONVERSION[\"UTM zone 36N\",\n        METHOD[\"Transverse Mercator\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9807]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",33,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Scale factor at natural origin\",0.9996,\n            SCALEUNIT[\"unity\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8805]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",500000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"(E)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"(N)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Engineering survey, topographic mapping.\"],\n        AREA[\"Between 30°E and 36°E, northern hemisphere between equator and 84°N, onshore and offshore. Belarus. Cyprus. Egypt. Ethiopia. Finland. Israel. Jordan. Kenya. Lebanon. Moldova. Norway. Russian Federation. Saudi Arabia. Sudan. Syria. Türkiye (Turkey). Uganda. Ukraine.\"],\n        BBOX[0,30,84,36]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",32636]]"

and terra::crs(p173r62)
"PROJCRS[\"WGS 84 / UTM zone 35N\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n        DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4326]],\n    CONVERSION[\"UTM zone 35N\",\n        METHOD[\"Transverse Mercator\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9807]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",27,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Scale factor at natural origin\",0.9996,\n            SCALEUNIT[\"unity\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8805]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",500000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"(E)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"(N)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Engineering survey, topographic mapping.\"],\n        AREA[\"Between 24°E and 30°E, northern hemisphere between equator and 84°N, onshore and offshore. Belarus. Bulgaria. Central African Republic. Democratic Republic of the Congo (Zaire). Egypt. Estonia. Finland. Greece. Latvia. Lesotho. Libya. Lithuania. Moldova. Norway. Poland. Romania. Russian Federation. Sudan. Svalbard. Türkiye (Turkey). Uganda. Ukraine.\"],\n        BBOX[0,24,84,30]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",32635]]"

Merging images on the same path works fine. p173 <- terra::merge(p173r61, p173r62)

However when I try to project path 172 to the crs of path 173 it crops the data.
p172 <- terra::merge(p172r61, p172r62) |>
   terra::project(p173)
plot(p172)


It looks like it crops the data at 30 East which is the bound for the BBOX in the CRS for p173. When I merge the data, it works well enough but all of the cropped information is gone past 30 West.

If I try to project both to a different CRS, specifically "EPSG:4326", then the resolution of the two images is slightly different, and so won't merge.
How could you get these images to merge without cropping the data, and generally what is the best (or a decent) CRS to use?

I have an unrelated bonus question about why the format of terra::plot changes after project? I think it looks much nicer in the first image.

I think this question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206519/combining-utm-zones is similar, but I would like to see a coded solution

What exactly are you planning to do next after you have merged your imagery? Is this just for visualization purposes or are you going to run some pixel-by-pixel analyses?

I'm going to interact this data on canopy coverage (every five years), along with Hansen yearly data on deforestation, and aggregate at the village level. So I'll end up with something like yearly area of deforested canopy cover. I'll already have to reproject the canopy cover data as it has a slightly different resolution than the Ha send deforestation data.

These images don't need to be reprojected because they fall into different UTM zones. Rwanda falls in 4 zones (35N, 35S, 36N, 36S). See here: 
Reprojecting to the wrong UTM zone will forcibly alter the longitudinal placement of the image.
The units for UTM are meters, so when you project to EPSG:4326 you are converting to degrees, which introduces some error. If you want to get them both into a common CRS, try EPSG:3857, which is also in meters.
For reference: https://www.xmswiki.com/wiki/UTM_Coordinate_System
UTM_OVERVIEW
You can customize the color ramp for your terra:plot() outputs using the 'col' argument. (https://rspatial.github.io/terra/reference/plot.html)

Thanks! However when I project the two paths to "EPSG:3857", they now have slightly different resolution `> res(p172)
[1] 30.14799 30.14799

res(p173)
[1] 30.14966 30.14966` So they won't merge.


Try setting the 'res' argument to 30.15 in the project() function calls. https://rdrr.io/github/rspatial/terra/man/project.html

I also need to set the origin to 0,0. This is the code that works for me p173 <- terra::merge(p173r61, p173r62)  p172 <- terra::merge(p172r61, p172r62)  p172 <- project(p172, "EPSG:3857", res = 30.15, origin = c(0,0)) p173 <- project(p173, "EPSG:3857", res = 30.15, origin = c(0,0)) combined <- merge(p172, p173)

I guess at this point it works, but I wonder how much it reshuffled around the data. Was this basically taking a hammer to it, when there might have been some other way? Either way, I was hoping to accept an answer that has code and a final image. Any chance you might update your answer to incorporate that?
